# Searching for *=

Tags: support, search

Is there a way to search for `*=` as a string?

I'm pretty sure [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731413/sql-operator) is a dupe but searching for `*=` doesn't return anything.

Comment: I suspect it is simply too short as a search string.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428144/sql-what-does-mean

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67709/153020

Answer (score 6):

This question is like a lot of others asked on here about how to search for special characters. I finally made a solution, and posted it here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113531/173360

> SymbolHound is a search engine that allows you to do these kinds of searches: http://symbolhound.com/
>
> Its index right now is almost entirely Stack Overflow, although that should change in the future as its index grows to include all programming sites. If you only want to search SO there's an advanced search feature where you can limit the search by site.
>
> Full disclosure: I am a co-founder and developer of SymbolHound.

Your example looks like it gets good results on SymbolHound: [http://symbolhound.com/?q=*%3D](http://symbolhound.com/?q=*=) (of course if those aren't relevant you'd want to add the language for which you want to know the meaning of *=, eg search for 'SQL *=')

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't answer you *question*, but for your *problem*, I suggest searching for "ansi join".

Comment: Or the even simpler, wait for someone else to find and copy them... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

[You can now search for symbols](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange).  To search for terms of only (or including) symbols just use quotes like this: ["*="](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22*%3D%22).