# Ability to search for C--

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

I'm finding it impossible to search for [C--](http://www.cminusminus.org/) on Stackoverflow. It doesn't seem to have a tag either. Is this a limitation of the search system Stackoverflow uses?

Comment: What's `C--`???

Comment: @Mysticial My first question too.  Turns out, *it's hard to search for!*  [It does exist though](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C--).

Comment: @Mysticial http://www.cminusminus.org/

Comment: There is [a `c-minus-minus` tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c-minus-minus).

Comment: I'm mildly surprised that the wiki article is not on the first page of hits on Google.

Comment: @hammar with 3 questions in it

Comment: @KateGregory Looks like it didn't catch on

Comment: Fortunately `C+-` is just still `C` :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There IS such a tag: [c-minus-minus](/questions/tagged/c-minus-minus). It's just not used very much.

There isn't a "c--" tag because it doesn't conform to the current tag naming rules; anyone attempting to use "c--" as a tag will see it automatically converted to "c". This might explain why some C-- questions are tagged as [c](/questions/tagged/c) instead. If you do come across these, do retag them to [c-minus-minus](/questions/tagged/c-minus-minus).

As for search, unfortunately [punctuations and symbols are not currently accounted for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67704/how-to-search-and-or-on-stackoverflow/67709#67709) and so [a search for "C--"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22c--%22) gives the [same results as "C"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22c%22) <sup><sup>1</sup></sup>.

An alternative would be to [use SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/?q=c--&u=stackoverflow.com), however for such a short (and ambiguous) term you may need to wade through quite a few false positives.

#### Update:

Using the [new search engine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange/), it is now possible to [search for "C--"](https://stackoverflow.com/search-new?q=%22C--%22) (quotes required).

---

<sup>**Footnotes:**</sup>

<sup><sup>1</sup> [Google does not deal with "C--" either](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q="c--").</sup>

Comment: In case anyone's interested, I wrote a user script for this purpose: [SymbolHound Search](http://stackapps.com/q/3181)

Comment: Hmm - searching for "C--" (with quotes), does not give me any results.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to search for c-- is to use the `code:` search operator, as in [code:"c--"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=code:%22c--%22&submit=search) , although it just returns questions where c-- is inside code tags.

I tried with [`body:"c--"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=body:%22c--%22&submit=search), but it just searches for c, and [`body:"c\-\-"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=body:%22c%5C-%5C-%22&submit=search), but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

As [Shawn's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148719/135201) notes, you can now search for terms with symbols like this just by using quotes.

For example [search for "C--"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22c--%22)